# How to deploy Question2Answer to the cloud via a Google App Engine instance?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, gcloud, question2answer

I'm trying to deploy Question2Answer (Q2A) by following this [official install guide](http://www.question2answer.org/install.php) - where we need to set up

1. A web server to push Q2A source code to - [uploading application folder to App Engine instance](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/uploading) matched with this.
2. A MySQL database and the according log-in account - this is matched by [creating](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/#create) and [configuring](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/#PHP_Grant_your_App_Engine_application_access_to_the_Google%20Cloud%20SQL_instance) a Cloud SQL instance to work with our app engine instance.

Though I failed to get Q2A run on Google's cloud - as browing the deployed web I get the error as below snapshot.

How would you guys get it deployed successfully?

[image]

p.s.

Steps I have made to Q2A's PHP source code

1. Entering MySQL database access credentials (by following [this guide](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/#mysql_api_connecting_from_app_engine))

[image]

2. Adding `app.yaml` file so as Google App Engine SDK would deploy Q2A application

[image]

The Q2A source code folder I'm working with is as below.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You just need to remove the root password and leave it like this:

```
define('QA_MYSQL_PASSWORD', '');
```

You can find [at the documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/#PHP_Connect_to_your_database) that "when you connect from App Engine, you can use the root user and no password"

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'll try that. Thank you! Though I think I have configure my Cloud SQL database with a password already.